# How would I execute python in vb.net without a temporary file?

Tags: python, vb.net

I'm trying to rework the launcher of my multi-player on-line game to include a little bit of security. I want to run python without a temporary file or `Process.Start()`. I'm currently using a batch wrapper for python to execute it, like so:

```
Dim sb3 As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb3.AppendLine("@echo off&cd C:/ToontownRebuilt/src/dependencies &""panda/python/ppython.exe"" -x %0 %*    &goto :eof")
sb3.AppendLine("# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-")
sb3.AppendLine("import(sys)")
sb3.AppendLine("reload(sys) # Reload does the trick!")
sb3.AppendLine("sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')")
sb3.AppendLine("sys.path.append('/')")
sb3.AppendLine("from pandac.PandaModules import *")
sb3.AppendLine("import rebuilt")
sb3.AppendLine("from toontown.toonbase import ClientStartDist")
Dim secretsus As String
secretsus = sb3.ToString()
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TTRB_GAMESERVER", "toontownrebuilt.dynu.com")
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TTRB_PLAYCOOKIE", username)
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ttrbUsername", username)
Dim oShell As Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run("cmd /K " & vbCrLf & secretsus)
oShell = Nothing
```

But that returns with:

> ```
> panda/python/ppython.exe: can't open file '%0': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

Is there any other way to do this?

Any & all help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure of your path where python.exe is located ? Because that's what your error is saying...

Comment: I know, It's `C:\ToontownRebuilt\src\dependencies`. I fixed that after posting. It says can't open %0 now.

Comment: Please edit your question or post a new one as your problem has changed...

Comment: It's midnight atm, my computer is turned off, I think I'll edit it in the morning as soon as I wake.

Comment: Edited, sorry about the wait.

Comment: You should look how you are supposed to call that exe... What is `%0` supposed to be ? What does `%*` mean ?

Comment: It pretty much tries to find itself and -x skips first line of source, successfully creating a hybrid script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making the python script a one liner and running it with `python -c "code here (quotes included)"`, i was able to do this.